# Pointing Web-Application and Native Application to same database/back-end?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, web-applications, service

I am creating a `web application` with a `Java` back end. I intend to house this on `Amazon Web Services`.

Ideally, in the future, I would like to create a Native `Android` application that carries the *same* functionality as the web app.

How can I implement my current application so that the `Native App` and `Web App` can both use the *same* back end database and services?

I have been reading about [Service Orientated Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture), is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service Orientated Architecture (SOA) is an approach that has been around for a while and could certainly meet your requirements. However I would caution you that you are going to run into lots of "Enterprise" designs as you search for information about SOA that will really be overkill for the type of development you are doing.

In general I would simply recommend that you focus on the following:

- Keep your UI (HTML/JS/CSS) in a separate project from the Java back end. This practice will force you to keep the UI and back end concerns separate.
- Have your back end expose an API that sends and receives JSON via HTTP/HTTPS.
- Make your back end services stateless. Using JSON web tokens for authentication is a good way to accomplish this (I like using [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) for this). In other words don't rely on an HTTP session to track your users from within your Java code. This has the added benefit of making your application really easy to scale.

If you do these things then when it comes time to build the Android app you wont have to touch the back end at all. You will just have to implement the UI again in native Android.

---

Since you tagged this question with AWS I assume you plan to implement your back end on AWS. If so, I would highly recommend you look into using Amazon's [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) service. This service would sit between your UI layer and your back end. This provides several advantages such as rate limiting and caching to secure your API from DDOS attacks, an optional API key for added security, and API versioning to help you deploy new versions of your API without breaking existing clients. Also, by defining your API using the API Gateway service you can then generate an SDK for your API for use in JavaScript, Android and iOS.

Another big advantage of using API Gateway is that it allows you to break up your back end into separate servers, Lambda functions, etc. This allows for great flexibility, and I can't stress enough how the ability to use AWS Lambda in your back end will reduce administrative work as well as hosting costs. This enables you to start thinking about your back end in terms of [Microservices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices).

Comment: Thank you for an incredibly detailed answer. I assume that I would still be hosting all my code on AWS, aside from the android app, i.e. the UI and back-end java api will both be on AWS? Also, how would my Android App communicate with this back end, would it be using REST?

Comment: You can host this all on AWS, although the HTML/JS/CSS could probably exist as static resources on S3 instead of having to serve those via the same server that your Java application runs on (Tomcat?). Your Android app would communicate with the back end via the same methods and protocols that your browser-based JavaScript uses to communicate with the back end. I hesitated to specify REST as that is a specific standard that you may not want to implement. I just specified JSON over HTTP. You could certainly go with REST.

Comment: I guess REST is more of a "style" than a "standard" but anyway it is one way to accomplish JSON over HTTP which is how you would communicate with your back end.

Comment: Thank you I understand now, so the Java Application will run on a tomcat server from within AWS? I am only learning the basics of AWS at the min, I apologise if that's a very simple question.

Comment: Yes you could use Elastic Beanstalk or simply create an EC2 server. Both of these services provide Linux servers that you can run Tomcat on. Elastic Beanstalk provides some management of that for you. If you are really new to AWS I recommend using Elastic Beanstalk because it manages things like server creation, server and application monitoring, scaling and load balancing for you, while still giving you the ability to tweak all those settings.

Comment: Thank you, did you find AWS a tough learning curve to being with? It seems to be well worth learning!

Comment: Yes, there is so much to learn with all the different AWS services it takes years to learn it all.

Comment: ok, should I go with something more simple to being with, to host my app? I.e. other than AWS?

Comment: The only other hosting service I would recommend looking into at this time is Heroku, which is a PaaS similar to Elastic Beanstalk but generally simpler to use. And since it runs on AWS you can still integrate it with some AWS services if you need to.

Comment: ok, do I need to buy a domain name from someone else e.g. HostGator in order to create a name for my site, or can I do this in AWS?

Comment: You can buy a domain on AWS through Route53, but you don't have to buy it there. It really doesn't matter where you buy it.